# What does “fondi finalizzate al recupero” mean?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, grammar, adjectives

While learning Italian today by translating and reading some texts, I stumbled upon this part of a sentence “...grazie alla promozione e alla raccolta dei fondi finalizzate al recupero...”. I understand the sentence and I’ve also translated the part mentioned in the title of the post, so I understand it all. What I have a problem with, however, is the use of the word “finalizzate” here... What is it? An adjective, a verb, an adverb, what? So it seems most logical that it is an adjective, but how come? I mean it ends with “e” and it goes with “fondi” which is plural noun in “maschile” (I don’t know how to say that in English sorry). Because of that I find it very strange it ends with “e” and not “i”. Can anybody help figure this out?

Comment: Depending on where the text is from, it could also be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that *finalizzate* refers to *promozione* and *raccolta*. The language is a bit involute, but looks correct.

Comment: Oooooh okay, thank you very much!